# Combo and SFP ports

Tags: networking, router

I have Netgear GSM7324s prosafe switch. Switch has 24x1G ports. 4 ports are labeled as combo ports while 2 are labeled as SFP ports. I connected 2 PCs (each having 1gig and 10Gig NICs), with the switch using 1 & 10 Gig cables. Whenever, I ping the PCs the pinging is not working. As soon as, I removed the 10G cables, the ping starts working.

Can someone please explain that what's going on. Also it would be very helpful if you can tell me the concept of combo ports, SFP ports in easy words?

Thanks in advance...

Comment: @jchips12 no, serverfault is for professional admins...

Comment: @Alnitak thanks for pointing out, I deleted my comment to avoid confusion.

Answer (score 1):

Combo Ports mean they are shared Between the SFP and the Copper port.  So you can use 1 or the other but not both at the same time.  So if GI/24 is combo port you can either have  a Cable plugged into the Copper 10/100/1000 interface, or the cable plugged into the SFP. If you have both plugged in, only 1 will work. Also the 7324s doesn't appear to support 10GE.

you can run multiple Ethernets from the PC, but will need to look into NIC Teaming, Bonding, LACP or some other form form of aggregation to make it work. Again making sure that they are not connected to both ports in the combo interface.